# OSX make two drives appear as continuous volume

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine

I want two drives to appear as one continuous volume on OSX

how would this be done?

they are both connected via sata

ultimately this will be shared over a network from the OSX file server. And even more ideally, this will function as a time machine backup.

Comment: Check out http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69538/can-i-make-a-diy-fusion-drive, which is instructions for creating a Fusion Drive via OSX Core Storage. I'm no expert, but I see no reason why this shouldn't work with two HDDs instead of a SSD and a HDD.

Answer (score 1):

Here are [Apple's instructions for using Disk Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH5834) to create a RAID set.

Of course, knowing more about your hardware (the computer we are talking about, etc) could improve answers and how specific they get.

Comment: okay, so I can combine partitions across physical drives? I speculate that I'll have a slimmed down OSX partition on one of the drives, and then combine a large partition of storage on the rest of that drive, and the entire partition of the second drive. If this is how I understand it

Comment: @RD sounds like you would follow the instructions for **Create a concatenated disk set** on that page then, and since it doesn't come with any warning about needing to boot to a separate disc to be able to include the boot drive in the set... apparently you can set up that array the way you describe.